# breaking an array in array

Tags: php, api

I want to output an array, row by row, based on the output given.

I’ve tried the following with no success. The output is not what I expect.

(all data is in $value)

```
$result=$value;

foreach($returnOrders as $key_1 => $val_1){
    if($key_1=='failed'){
        foreach($val_1 as $key_2 => $val_2){
            if($key_2=='success'){
                foreach($val_2 as $key_3 => $val_3){
                    echo $key_3 ."=>".$val_3;
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Show us the value of `$returnOrders`[please add as a code, not picture]. Also add the expected outcome you want. [same as code, not an image]. Otherwise it's really hard to understand what's going on?

Comment: I don't think `success` should be nested under `failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want two separate loops, not nested loops.

```
echo "Sucess:<br>";
foreach ($returnOrders['success'] as $order) {
    var_dump($order);
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "Failed:<br>";
foreach ($returnOrders['failed'] as $order) {
    var_dump($order);
    echo "<br>";
}
```